# jQuery how to activate one event for multiple elements with same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple divs with different id names, like this:

```
<div id="person1">
    <img class="imgPerson" src="../images/person1.jpg">
    <div class="personBubble" style="display: none;">
        <div class="extraInfo">
            Sells carrots
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="person2">
    <img class="imgPerson" src="../images/person2.jpg">
    <div class="personBubble" style="display: none;">
        <div class="extraInfo">
            Sells onions
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="person3">
    <img class="imgPerson" src="../images/person3.jpg">
    <div class="personBubble" style="display: none;">
        <div class="extraInfo">
            Sells lettuce
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I have `person1, person2, person3`. 
I also have this jQuery function that sets `display:block` for the `personBubble` class when `imgPerson` is on hover.

```
$(".imgPerson").hover(
    function () {
        $(".personBubble").fadeIn(150);
    },
    function () {
        $(".personBubble").fadeOut(150);
});
```

However, obviously every `personBubble` class is set to `display:block` when the event is activated, since they all have the same name. I only want this to happen to the corresponding `personBubble`, i.e. if the `imgPerson` of person1 is on hover, only the `personBubble` of person1 should be set to `display: block`.

What is the best way to achieve this without having to use unique IDs for every person and having to write the same jQuery function for each one of those IDs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to the `this` object which points to the current context and call `siblings()` method to search for a sibling with respective class name `.personBubble` inside current context.

```
$(".imgPerson").hover(
    function () {
       $(this).siblings(".personBubble").fadeIn(150);
    },
    function () {
       $(this).siblings(".personBubble").fadeOut(150);
   }
);
```

[Live Demo @ JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/uw8uc2nx/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use event source object using `$(this)` to get next `personBubble`

```
$(".imgPerson").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).next(".personBubble").fadeIn(150);
    },
    function () {
        $(this).next(".personBubble").fadeOut(150);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

since `imgPerson` and `personBubble` are siblings, all you have to do is use siblings()

and I suggest you use fadeToggle() it makes your code shorter, shorter is better.

```
$(".imgPerson").hover(function(){
   $(this).siblings().fadeToggle(150);
});
```